# Magento 2 : How to Include New Fonts

Tags: magento2, theme, less-css, fonts

I have added new fonts in `<my theme>/web/fonts`, and declared those fonts in `<my_theme>/web/css/source/_typography.less`. But still my custom fonts not reflecting in my pages.

I'm missing any configurations? anybody have idea over here?

Comment: IS the browser attempting to load the font? Is there a 404 error?

Comment: no, it is still picking the default fonts.

Comment: Could you please show the `<theme_dir>/web/css/source/_typography.less` file code?

Comment: similar to blank theme _typography.less, https://www.screencast.com/t/RoFChdMyrNi

Comment: Have you cleared all caches and deleted `var/view_preprocessed` and `pub/static/frontend`?

Comment: yeah it was done.

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 9):

You can add your custom font in your custom theme, creating the `custom.css` file and include css in the `default_head_blocks.xml` like the below files:

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\CustomTheme\Magento_Theme\layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/custom.css" /> 
    </head>
</page>
```

And then put your fonts in the below custom theme directory.

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\CustomTheme\web\fonts**

And include your custom fonts in the `custom.css` code like below:

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\CustomTheme\web\css/custom.css**

```
/*------------fontcss-------------*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display';
    src: url('../fonts/sitefont/Playfair Display.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/sitefont/Playfair Display.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/sitefont/Playfair Display.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/sitefont/Playfair Display.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/sitefont/Playfair Display.svg#Playfair Display') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
 unicode-range: U+0020-2212;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    src: url('../fonts/sitefont/Century Gothic.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/sitefont/Century Gothic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/sitefont/Century Gothic.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/sitefont/Century Gothic.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/sitefont/Century Gothic.svg#Century Gothic') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
 unicode-range: U+0020-F003;
}
```

After including the fonts, run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command.

Hope this help. It's working for me.

Comment: I have tried with the Magento 2 way like using _typography.less file. and now it works fine.

Comment: Thanks in future I will use the Magento 2 way to use the custom fonts.

Comment: @seeni Can you please help me in loading fonts in emails. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @SejalShah, did you get any solution ?

Comment: Thank you ! ! ! It worked on magento 2.3.4 version.

Answer (score 2):

Add font in your theme web/fonts folder

```
app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/fonts
```

Create your @font-face rule. In file:

```
src/app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/source/_typography.less
```

insert code

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
  .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-ExtraLight',
    @font-weight: 200,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
  );

  .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-Light',
    @font-weight: 300,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
  );

  .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-Regular',
    @font-weight: 400,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
  );

  .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-Bold',
    @font-weight: 700,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
  );

  .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-ExtraBold',
    @font-weight: 800,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
  );
}
```

This code will generate @font-face rules in style-m.css. Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BioRhyme';
  src: url('../fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-ExtraLight.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-ExtraLight.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BioRhyme';
  src: url('../fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-Light.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-Light.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BioRhyme';
  src: url('../fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-Regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BioRhyme';
  src: url('../fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-Bold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BioRhyme';
  src: url('../fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-ExtraBold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/BioRhyme/BioRhyme-ExtraBold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Override font you like. For example add in your theme css/source/_theme.less

```
//
//  Fonts
//  ---------------------------------------------

@font-family-name__base: 'BioRhyme';
```

You can also embed it from external link like Google Font https://fonts.google.com/

Edit this file

```
src/app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

and insert your code for example:

```
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=BioRhyme:wght@300;400;700" rel="stylesheet"  src_type="url" />
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Along with the `_typography.less` change, `variables.less` file also need update. Instead of `Open sans` font we have to declare our custom font. Then it works fine.

Comment: Have you did any other thing ? because i have change _typography.less and _variables.less  both file but font is still not update

Answer (score 0):

1. Add font files to your local theme directory. For example, app/design/frontend///web/fonts.
2. If you build a theme using the Magento UI library, declare the font by adding the .lib-font-face mixin to the app/design/frontend///web/css/source/_typography.less file:

   .lib-font-face(
   @family-name:'',
   @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/',
   @font-weight: ,
   @font-style: 
   @font-display: 
   );
   3- You must edit the app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml file to declare your fonts; otherwise, Magento 2.3 is not able to create the static/web/fonts/ directory. See app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml.

@font-display: swap is declared by default for Magento Blank theme in app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/source/_typography.less.

Fallback web fonts that are used by default in Magento are located in lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_typography.less.