# What is the steps to include custom fonts in a newly created theme in magento 2 using typography.less?

Tags: custom, magento2.3.2, fonts

I am adding a custom font in my newly created theme in magento 2. Below are the steps which i am doing:

***1. Placed custom fonts in***

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/Theme_name/web/fonts
```

***2) Added_typography.less in***

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/Theme_name/web/css/source
```

and added
    the font-face mixin in it.

***3) Now, overriding the Font-face variable in _theme.less***

But somehow its not working. I tried defining the font-face mixins and adding font-face-base variable in ***_extends.less.***

Still not clear what is the best way to define a custom font. Can somebody suggest the standard way.

Answer (score 0):

**Refernce Link Form include Custom Fonts:-**

> [https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-custom-fonts/](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/164859/72911)
>
> [https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/164859/72911](https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-custom-fonts/)
>
> [Dev Doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html)
>
> https://inchoo.net/magento/custom-typography-in-magento-font-face/