# How can we set a google font family as a base font for the magento store

Tags: magento2

I have added the google font to my custom Magento 2 theme in `default_head.xml` file. Now I need to set the font family as my base font

Where do I need to set the font family?

Comment: Below links will help you, still you have doubts, please let me know.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164850/magento-2-how-to-include-new-fonts

Comment: @Nits Cant we use _typography.less approach. cnould you give some example for that also